# Access to validation_data Keras while using GridsearchCV

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback, gridsearchcv

I would like to build a pipeline for parameters tuning using GridsearchCV. My model is a (binary) classifier and I built it using Keras Sequential().

Since I am dealing with a skew dataset (about 6/7 labels are 0 and left with 1/7 part of the data seta labelled with 1) I added a callback which computes the f1, recall and precision metrics at the end of each epoch, which I want to use as metrics to validate my model.

In order to do so, I am using a callback in Keras which needs to specify my validation dataset in the fit() instance for my model. This, in turn, makes really hard to access the validation set and to use GridsearchCV.

I managed to overcome this by building a sort of DIY cv procedure but I was wondering if this can be implemented more efficiently in combination with GridsearchCV.
Here's my code:

SETTING DIFFERENT THRESHOLDS FOR CLASSIFICATION

*INPUT:  x, the vector of predictions produced by the NN learning
        thr, the threshold we use to classify the predictions into 0 or 1 class.
OUTPUT: a vector containing 0 and 1, the labels of the messages predicted*

```
def pred_round(x,thr):
    x=np.array(x)
    if 0<thr<1:
        return 1*(x >thr)
```

Then I create the callback for my metrics:

```
class Metrics(Callback):

def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
    self.val_f1s = []
    self.val_recalls = []
    self.val_precisions = []

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    val_predict = pred_round(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]), threshold)
    val_targ = self.validation_data[1]
    _val_precision, _val_recall, _val_f1, dummy = precision_recall_fscore_support(val_targ, val_predict,beta = 1.0,average = 'binary')
    self.val_f1s.append(_val_f1)
    self.val_recalls.append(_val_recall)
    self.val_precisions.append(_val_precision)
metrics = Metrics()
```

I then create the model by using:

```
def create_model(optimizer="adam", dropout=0.1, init='uniform'):
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1,input_shape=(N_FEATURES,), kernel_initializer=init,))  
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = OPTIMIZER,
            #metrics=['accuracy','binary_accuracy']
            )
return model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=1)
N_FEATURES = X_train.shape[1]
thresholds = [0.2,0.3,0.5] #0.15
EPOCHS =200
BATCH_SIZE = 256
VERBOSE = 1
OPTIMIZER = Adadelta()
N_HIDDEN = 2000
cv_repetitions = 5
```

#### Now the part of the code that I wish to optimise:

```
for threshold in thresholds:
    i=0
    f1_cv_scores = np.zeros(EPOCHS)
    recall_cv_scores = np.zeros(EPOCHS)
    precision_cv_scores = np.zeros(EPOCHS)
    loss_train_scores = np.zeros(EPOCHS)
    loss_cv_scores = np.zeros(EPOCHS)
    for i in range(cv_repetitions):
        i+=1
        X_train_NN, X_val_NN, y_train_NN, y_val_NN = train_test_split(X_train,y_train,test_size= 0.2,stratify = y_train)


        history = model.fit( x= X_train_NN, y= y_train_NN,
                            batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                            validation_data = (X_val_NN,y_val_NN),
                            epochs = EPOCHS,
                            verbose = VERBOSE,
                            callbacks = [metrics]
                            )
        loss_train_scores += history.history['loss']
        loss_cv_scores   += history.history['val_loss']
        f1_cv_scores += metrics.val_f1s
        recall_cv_scores += metrics.val_recalls
        precision_cv_scores += metrics.val_precisions

    loss_train_scores = loss_test_scores/cv_repetitions
    loss_cv_scores   = loss_cv_scores/cv_repetitions
    f1_cv_scores     = f1_cv_scores /cv_repetitions
    recall_cv_scores = recall_cv_scores/cv_repetitions
    precision_cv_scores = precision_cv_scores/cv_repetitions
```

Is there a way to enclose these loops using GridsearchCV and perhaps include more parameters for the cross-validation part?

Thank you in advance for reading and the help.